# Format Number in an Analytic Chart / Performace Point

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

Is it possible to specify the format of numbers in an analytic chart?

So far, I know it's possible to give a number that belongs to a dashboard. Not so, to an analytic chart.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can select the number formatting for the analysis chart by using performancepoint designer and going to the Edit -> Format numbers in the ribbon.

If you are using your own MDX you can use FORMAT_STRING. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879322.aspx where you can find examples as:

`with
member measures.A as 5040, FORMAT_STRING="Currency"`